# POST id objects and retriving nested tables related to it

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, filter, django-rest-framework

Can someone advise me on how to deal with how to retrieve data such as this example
JSON:

```
[
    {       
            "deviceid": 4,
            "devicename": "###", 
            "device_measurment": {
                    "deviceid": 4,
                    "measurement": "31.8",
                 }   
    },
 ]
    
How is it right now:

 [
    {       
            "deviceid": 4,
            "devicename": "###",     
    },
    {
       
            "deviceid": 4,
            "measurement": "31.8",
    },
 ]
```

I understand the problem and why I am getting such a response, but I cannot handle this problem via the serializer. at the moment, I have the following

**Views**

```
from itertools import chain

    class RetrieveSpecificDevicesView(APIView):
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
  serializer_class = SpecificDeviceSerializer
  


  def post(self, request):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':      
       serializer = SpecificDeviceSerializer(data=request.data)

       if serializer.is_valid():
          obj1= Devices.objects.using('@@@').filter(deviceid=serializer.data.get("deviceid"))
          obj2= Measurements.objects.using('@@@').filter(deviceid=serializer.data.get("deviceid"))
          dats= chain(obj1, obj2)
          data = serializers.serialize('json', dats)
          return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")

       return JsonResponse(serializer.erorr, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**Serializer**

```
    class SpecificDeviceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
      deviceid = serializers.CharField(required=True)


class MeasurmentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
      model = Measurements
      fields = ('measurementid','measurement')
```

**Models**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r0VK.png)

**Update:**
I am trying to implement via serializer but something is going wrong:
**Note:** By wrong I mean => *Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `devicesname` on serializer `SpecificDeviceSerializer*`.

**Views**

```
class RetrieveSpecificDevicesView(APIView):
  permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
  serializer_class = SpecificcDeviceSerializer
  
  def post(self, request):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':      
       data = self.serializer_class.get_device(self, obj=request.data)
       user = SpecificDeviceSerializer(data)
       return HttpResponse(user)
```

**Serializers**

```
class SpecificDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 
  class Meta:
      model = Devices
      fields = ( 'deviceid', 'devicename') 
  
  

class SpecificcDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  def get_device(self, obj):
       device =  Devices.objects.using('@@@').filter(deviceid=obj.get("deviceid"))
       return device
  
  class Meta:
    model = Devices
    fields = ( 'deviceid', 'devicename')
```

Comment: Please add model.

Comment: see  image please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
**Serializer**

```
class SpecificDeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  measurments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  
  def get_measurments(self, obj):
       device_measurements = obj.measurment_details.last()  
       serializer = MeasurmentsSerializer(device_measurements)
       return serializer.data


  class Meta:
      model = Devices
      fields = ('devicename','measurments')
```

**Views**

```
class RetrieveSpecificDevicesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
      serializer_class = SpecificDeviceSerializer
      
      def get_queryset(self):  
          return Devices.objects.using('@@@').filter(deviceid=self.request.data.get("deviceid"))
```

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "devicename": "RTMU 3068",
        "measurments": {
            "measurementid": 2980465,
            "measurement": "25.6"
        }
    }
]
```

Documentation: [Best for this case](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)